# Find list intersection in Spark Core (Pyspark)

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

In my RDD I have a list of tuples, where each tuple is like this:

(UserID, [ProductsID1, ProductsID2, ProductsID3...])

For example:

```
('A395BORC6FGVXV', ['B001E4KFG0', 'B00813GRG4','B000LQOCH0','B006K2ZZ7K']),('A3SGXH7AUHU8GW', ['B001E4KFG0','B00813GRG4','B000LQOCH0']), ('AZOF9E17RGZH8', ['B001GVISJM']), ('ARYVQL4N737A1', ['B001GVISJM'])
```

From this, I have to create a result tuple whenever I meet two users that have rated more than 2 products in common and put the result tuple inside a new list

(UserID1, UserID2, [CommonProduct1, CommonProduct2, ...])

the only output of my example should be a list of 1 element like this:

```
('A395BORC6FGVXV', 'A3SGXH7AUHU8GW', ['B001E4KFG0', 'B00813GRG4','B000LQOCH0'])
```

How to do that in SparkCore (Pyspark)?

Answer (score 0):

df

```
df =spark.createDataFrame([('A395BORC6FGVXV', ['B001E4KFG0', 'B00813GRG4','B000LQOCH0','B006K2ZZ7K']),('A3SGXH7AUHU8GW', ['B001E4KFG0','B00813GRG4','B000LQOCH0']), ('AZOF9E17RGZH8', ['B001GVISJM']), ('ARYVQL4N737A1', ['B001GVISJM'])],('UserID' ,'Product'))

df.show(truncate=False)
```

Solution

```
 df=(df.withColumn('Product', explode('Product')).groupby('Product')#Product per row
    .agg(collect_list('UserID').alias('UserID')).groupby('UserID').agg(collect_list('Product').alias('product'))# aggregate lists of Users and Products
    .where(size(col('Product'))>=2)#Filter out where there exists more than two products per known groups of users
    .select(concat(lit('('),array_join('UserID',','),lit(' ['),array_join('Product',','),lit('])')).alias('string')))#Creates String required for output using concat
    df.show(truncate=False)
```

Outcome

```
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|string                                                            |
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
|(A395BORC6FGVXV,A3SGXH7AUHU8GW [B000LQOCH0,B00813GRG4,B001E4KFG0])|
+------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: It works but my specs was to avoid using spark sql. Do you have a solution in spark core?